# Connection refused while connection : MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2538'

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I'm trying to access a queue.

```
def mqProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>()
mqProps.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, 'CHANNEL')
mqProps.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, PORT)
mqProps.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, 'HOST')
mqProps.put(MQConstants.USER_ID_PROPERTY, 'myuser') // is it the correct property for the user? 
mqProps.put(MQConstants.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, 'mypassword') // is it the correct property for the password?

def qMgr = new MQQueueManager('QM', mqProps)
```

However I'm facing the following error

```
javax.script.ScriptException: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2538'
...
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2538'.
...
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'HOST(PORT)' rejected.
...
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'HOST/address:PORT' rejected.
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
...
```

The error happened on the line:

```
def qMgr = new MQQueueManager('QM', mqProps)
```

Can you please explain me reason of this issue? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Can you telnet to the same host and port, if you can then you will need to look at the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` for any additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason Code 2538 is [MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q045380_.htm).

You can quickly discover this by using the `mqrc` command line tool that comes with IBM MQ. Type:

```
mqrc 2538
```

and you will be told:

```
    2538  0x000009ea  MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

Alternatively you can look it up in the IBM MQ Knowledge Center.

Reading the explanation in Knowledge Center will show you a number of common possibilities for the problem.

- The listener has not been started on the remote system.
- The connection name in the client channel definition is incorrect.
- The network is currently unavailable.
- A firewall blocking the port, or protocol-specific traffic

Perhaps the most common of errors is that the listener running at the queue manager is not using the same port number that you have put in the client application connection details.

You haven't shown us in your question any details about the listener running on the queue manager, so we will have to leave that for you to check yourself.